# Options on how to create a PDF from a large webpage?

Tags: pdf, export

So let me start from the beginning from what I'm trying to do.

I use WP Engine, and I'm trying to download a copy of the Monthly Reports they provide in the dashboard.

The issue is that I have like 15 installs, each with a lot of traffic, and the monthly reports include stats for all of your sites, broken down daily. So, the page is massive, like almost a million lines.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to save this page as a PDF. When I go to Print the page and select "Save as PDF" it basically times out because the page is way too large.

What are my options here? Is there some way I can strip out all unnecessary info (like CSS) to try to slim down the page before saving to a PDF? Can I highlight a certain part of the page and export that selection as a PDF?

I'm looking for a slick way to export some of this data to a PDF.

Comment: Try a different web browser.  Try installing a "PDF printer", like CutePDF, and then just use browser's normal "Print" functionality to send to the printer.  A browser should be able to handle this, theoretically.  This ought to be pretty straightforward, but the reality is that sometimes the complexity of the web page's internal structure, and possibly combined with certain browser limitations/bugs/behavior, can make this not work too well.  In theory, though, your browser can get the info and show it on the screen, so software should be able to download it and get into a PDF. Just mightBwork

Answer (score 0):

If it's not a complex document, you could open in a text only browser, like `lynx` and just save the text

I'm pretty sure you can do that with command line switches

Comment: Good suggestion, but there are tables that I need to keep, that's mainly the only HTML I need. This would work if it didn't strip the tables.

Comment: Lynx used to make a good attempt to make tables work last time I tried it.  Maybe a huge table might break it if lynx had to go back and figure out the right maximum column width after thousands and thousands of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate workflow.

fetch the html with `wget` or `curl`.

open the html file with `LibreOffice`

save as PDF

idea stolen from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/320195/how-to-convert-a-html-file-to-pdf-with-colors)

Whether it works probably depends on how much js and css is in it.